# Is it possible to make an "if" in DBeaver SQL statement to test the current connection (Oracle, SQLServer, etc.)?

Tags: dbeaver

I'm configuring an DBeaver repository using [git extension](https://dbeaver.io/update/git/latest/), and making some scripts to share with my team. But we use multiple databases types, such as Oracle, SQL Server and DB2. I dont want to make the same script 3 times, each for a different database, because some functions are database specific.

Is there some trick to do this without having to repeat the script with the database functions? Something like [SQL Dialect Abstraction of Firedac](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Preprocessing_Command_Text_(FireDAC)) does.

Answer (score 0):

For my knowledge DBeaver doesn't have an Envirorment Variable which specify the current DB.

You can use a little trick; create 1 field custom table in every DB, and populate it with a single record with DB type (a custom value), and then use a `SQL CASE STATEMENT` to choose which SQL command run every time.

@EDIT

I found in `DB configuration -> Connection settings -> Shell Commands` 
a list of envirorment variable, I don't know how to use them but take a look:

```
${host} - target host
${port} - target port
${server}   - target server name
${database} - target database
${user} - user name
${password} - password (plain)
${url}  - JDBC URL
${workspace}    - workspace path
${home} - user home path
${dbeaver_home} - application install path
${application.name} - application name
${application.version}  - application version
${local.ip} - local IP address
```

Comment: It's a good trick, but I have almost 40 registered databases (not counting those that I have not registered yet), internal and production. The internals I could do that, but in production not. But thanks anyway